# How to compute the bracket of two different angular momentum eigenvectors?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum

how can I compute the bracket of two different angular momentum eigenvectors:

$$ \langle j_1 m_1 | j_2 m_2 \rangle $$

Answer (score 3):

$\vert j~ m \rangle$ is a shared eigenvector of two Hermitian operators ($J^2$ and $J_z$). Eigenvectors of Hermitian operators vanish if they don't correspond to the same eigenvalue, so
$$\langle j_1 m_1 \vert j_2 m_2 \rangle = \delta_{j_1j_2} \delta_{m_1 m_2}.$$